# Select query involving comparison between dates and time

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Here is my MS Sql table..
Table:
http://snag.gy/L6ag1.jpg

```
SELECT 
    * 
FROM Table1 
WHERE   
    Class = '12' 
    AND Section = 'B' 
    AND '3/4/2013' BETWEEN DATE AND TODATE 
    and '3/14/2013' between Date and ToDate 
    or '3/4/2013' < Date and '3/14/2013' > ToDate 
    AND (
            '12:00 PM'  between [StartTime] and endtime 
            and '1:00 PM' between [StartTime] and endtime 
            or ('12:00 PM' < StartTime and '1:00 PM' > EndTIme)
        )
```

The above query is returning all the 6 rows of the table while the below query returns 0 rows..

```
SELECT 
    * 
FROM Teacher 
WHERE   
    Class = '12' 
    AND Section = 'B' 
    and '12:00 PM'  between [StartTime] and endtime 
    and '1:00 PM' between [StartTime] and endtime 
    or ('12:00 PM' < StartTime and '1:00 PM' > EndTIme)
```

I was expecting the query at the top to return 0 rows since i used AND operand, so even if the date comparison returns rows the combined query shouldnt return anything since time comparison returns false.

SCRIPT TO CREATE TABLE:

```
INSERT INTO [SLIITComDB].[dbo].[Teacher]
           ([TeacherId]
           ,[TeacherName]
           ,[Class]
           ,[Section]
           ,[SubjectId]
           ,[Date]
           ,[ToDate]
           ,[Day]
           ,[StartTime]
           ,[EndTIme]
           ,[Absent])
     VALUES
           (<TeacherId, int,>
           ,<TeacherName, varchar(50),>
           ,<Class, varchar(50),>
           ,<Section, varchar(50),>
           ,<SubjectId, varchar(50),>
           ,<Date, date,>
           ,<ToDate, date,>
           ,<Day, varchar(50),>
           ,<StartTime, time(7),>
           ,<EndTIme, time(7),>
           ,<Absent, varchar,>)
GO
```

Comment: The datatype used are Date for dates and Time for column showing time.
THere is no error. SO it has to be logical fault.

Comment: why are you checking each condition twice?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In SQL, `AND` operator has precedence over `OR` operator.

So in your first query, the conditions look like this:

```
WHERE   
  ( Class = '12' 
    AND Section = 'B' 
    AND '3/4/2013' BETWEEN DATE AND TODATE 
    and '3/14/2013' between Date and ToDate
   ) OR (
    '3/4/2013' < Date and '3/14/2013' > ToDate 
    AND (
            '12:00 PM'  between [StartTime] and endtime 
            and '1:00 PM' between [StartTime] and endtime 
            or ('12:00 PM' < StartTime and '1:00 PM' > EndTIme)
        ))
```

The result is `TRUE` when either of the top or bottom sections (separated by `OR`) are `TRUE`.

The conditions in your second query also look like:

```
WHERE   
  ( Class = '12'
    AND Section = 'B' 
    and '12:00 PM'  between [StartTime] and endtime 
    and '1:00 PM' between [StartTime] and endtime
   )
    or ('12:00 PM' < StartTime and '1:00 PM' > EndTIme)
```

You first query can return result even if time comparisions are all `FALSE` because your first two date comparisions can be `TRUE`.

Answer (score 1):

Actually it is your OR which causes this:

The first part before the or is true according to your data. So these will be returned. Add brackets to clarify things.

True:

```
 Class = '12' 
    AND Section = 'B' 
    AND '3/4/2013' BETWEEN DATE AND TODATE 
    and '3/14/2013' between Date and ToDate 

 OR
```

False:

```
'3/4/2013' < Date and '3/14/2013' > ToDate 
    AND (
            '12:00 PM'  between [StartTime] and endtime 
            and '1:00 PM' between [StartTime] and endtime 
            or ('12:00 PM' < StartTime and '1:00 PM' > EndTIme)
        )
```

Try this simplified :

```
select * 
from Table1 
where 1 = 1
or 2 = 2
and 1 = 3
```